# Firebase Deploy Error: 'Changing secrets is not supported' when using separate projects with Stripe 'Run Payments with Stripe' extension

Tags: firebase, vue.js, environment-variables, quasar-framework, firebase-extensions

I'm trying to setup multiple environments for my Vue / Firebase Project.
I have two Firebase Projects
1.) Dev
2.) Prod
The project utilizes Stripe Extension which pulls the API Key from an auto-generated file called:
firestore-stripe-payments.env

which contains:

```
STRIPE_API_KEY=projects/${param:PROJECT_NUMBER}/secrets/firestore-stripe-payments-STRIPE_API_KEY-xxxx/versions/latest
```

Where xxxx is a random 4 character string.

That line pulls the value of the key from Google Secret Manager.

Let's say Dev is 'dddd'
and Prod is: 'pppp'

The issue is that I can only define either:

```
firestore-stripe-payments-STRIPE_API_KEY-dddd
```

or

```
firestore-stripe-payments-STRIPE_API_KEY-pppp
```

At first I tried to create a new value within Google Secret Manager simply called:

```
firestore-stripe-payments-STRIPE_API_KEY
```

The thought was this should be a simple fix, and it would pull the associated API_KEY for the project currently being used.

but this causes the error:

```
Error: firestore-stripe-payments: Found 'projects/foo/secrets/firestore-stripe-payments-STRIPE_API_KEY/versions/latest' for secret param STRIPE_API_KEY, but this instance was previously using a different secret projects/fooo/secrets/firestore-stripe-payments-STRIPE_API_KEY-dddd.
Changing secrets is not supported. If you want to change the value of this secret, use a new version of projects/foo/secrets/firestore-stripe-payments-STRIPE_API_KEY-dddd.You can create a new version at https://console.cloud.google.com/security/secret-manager?project=fooo
Also, if there is a better place to ask this question please let me know, couldn't find the 'right' room
```

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, could you include a separate env (`env.dev`) file using the following [guidelines](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes)

```
.env                # loaded in all cases
.env.local          # loaded in all cases, ignored by git
.env.[mode]         # only loaded in specified mode
.env.[mode].local
```

For generating separate keys for each environment, I believe from your example you are using a single `Stripe Extension` on a single project.

Firebase Extensions can support multiple instances of an Extension per project, this will create a separate "dev" secret for you to use.

Additionally, a separate Firebase project with another "Stripe Extension" installation would be recommended to separate any concerns in development.

Comment: I have two seperate Firebase projects. However it becomes a challenge because when you install the stripe extension from the web interface it creates a 'firestore-stipe-payments.env' file which defines your STRIPE_API_KEY. However for each environment if I generate the key, it overwrites the firestore-stripe-payments.env file.

This would be ok, if I could simply have the key named the same thing. Then it could pull from Google Secret Manager based on which project it currently is in. However I configure the extension it won't allow me to change the key